# what is missing from this rewrite

Tags: php, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have a site with a few pages. I also have several categories and child categories I have tried Mod Rewrite Rules in .htaccess but it's not working. The second rewrite rule for users and Sellers worked but the categories rewrite rule is not working.

My Setup is Apache Server, PHP System, SQL Database.

Here is what I am trying to do.

This is the current category links structure in PHP

Main Category
https://www.inoconn.com/category?cat_id=2

Child Category
https://www.inoconn.com/category?cat_child_id=17

What I am trying to accomplish is the following.

Main Category
https://www.inoconn.com/marketing/

Child Category
https://www.inoconn.com/marketing/seo/

Here is my htaccess code.

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} (.+)/$
RewriteRule ^ %1 [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}\.php -f 
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1.php

RewriteRule ^category/([-\w]+)/(\d+)$ category.php?url=$1&page=$2 [NC,L]

RewriteRule ^([0-9a-zA-Z-_-]+)$ user.php?seller_user_name=$1
```

What I am trying to accomplish is the following.

Comment: The URLs you said you want to accomplish don’t even contain the prefix `category` any more, so what exactly do you expect `RewriteRule ^category/…` to match?

Answer (score 0):

Check this rules on top of your .htaccess file

```
RewriteRule ^marketing/$ /category?cat_id=2 [L]
RewriteRule ^marketing/seo/$ /category?cat_child_id=17 [L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} (.+)/$
RewriteRule ^ %1 [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}\.php -f 
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1.php

RewriteRule ^category/([-\w]+)/(\d+)$ category.php?url=$1&page=$2 [NC,L]

RewriteRule ^([0-9a-zA-Z-_-]+)$ user.php?seller_user_name=$1
```